# Sorting of double values from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

In the database I keep records to which codes are assigned (double format).
When calling records from the database I would like them to be sorted from the smallest to the largest one.

The problem arises when 1.2 > 1.10 which is understandable.
I would like it to be interpreted as follows: 1.10 > 1.2

I tried to do this by changing the type to TEXT.
Adding spaces at the end of the "code".

I have an idea to divide the numbers into segments and if the first segment is equal then sort by the second segment. 
It seems logical, but I don't know how to translate it into code.

Could anyone help?

Comment: That looks like a bit complex to do it in SQL, do you mind if it's done in PHP when data arrives? If so, retreive them as text, then a good start would be to do `explode('.', $code);`

Comment: Those "numbers" are stored as varchar, right?

Comment: Tried stored as "varchar, text, etc."

Comment: How can you have a value `1.10` in a `double` type? it would be truncated to `1.1`. So how would you know if it was `1.1`, `1.10`, `1.100`, `...`?

Comment: I know, so I wrote that it is understandable to me why this happens. By the way, a change of type does not help.

Answer (score 1):

if your codes  contain a valid decimal value the you could try converting the codes in order by as couple of integer

```
select codes 
from my_table
order by  ( CAST(left(codes, locate('.', codes)-1 ) AS UNSIGNED), 
    CAST(right(codes, length(codes -locate('.', codes)) AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: wouldn't this lead to `1.2 > 1.10`, which the OP wants to avoid?

Comment: @Kaddath  thanks  ..  you are right  . answer  updated  for split in separated  integer  so 2 < 10  (and 1.2 < 1.10=

Comment: That's an elegant solution, this is easier than I thought

Comment: @Kaddath   ..tnanks  mysql  provides many features for these situations